# select a column from join table active query yii2

Tags: join, activerecord, yii2

I am try to select one column from a join table but i am getting the error : Undefined index: id

```
$jobHistory = Report::getDb()->cache(function($db){
            return Report::find()
                ->select('job_id')
                ->where(['status' => "Order Delivered"])
                ->andWhere(['>=', 'job_datetime', '2016-09-01'])
                ->andWhere(['<', 'job_datetime', '2016-09-03'])
                ->joinWith(['job' => function($a){
                    $a->select('order_placed');
                }])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
        });
```

Comment: This code ins not enough .. Update the question and add the  code where you call this function ..

Comment: change select(job_id) to select(table.job_id) try this i will work

Comment: @Dani. Thanks that works.